# Alto consumo de RAM

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, memória

Meu Visual Studio 2015 quando uso para debugar um projeto WEB C# MVC está com o seguinte consumo de RAM:

[image: Consumo de RAM do Visual Studio 2015]

Este consumo está normal? Meu computador fica muito lento quando tenho que testar alguma modificação em uma página.

Comment: Não tá normal mesmo, tá muito baixo. Fique feliz! Eu abri um projeto pra debuggar e tá em 1200MB.

Comment: Se o seu está baixo o meu está com anemia, rodo com 75MB de RAM kkk

Comment: No meu caso o que costumar travar qualquer aplicação é a leitura de disco chegar a 100%, então seu problema pode ser algum software que já esteja consumindo o disco (I/O) e o debugger do MSVC também consome o que ocasiona isto.

Comment: Meu VS2019 está parado, utilizando 500MB RAM.O problema deve ser a soma de várias aplicações, qual resulta em um elevado nível de utilização de RAM, CPU, Disco, etc. Reiniciar o computador pode ajudar ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Só isso? Eu diria que é pouco. Visual Studio, como todos os IDEs poderosos são devoradores de memória, provavelmente não há aplicação desktop que use tanta memória. Para usar bem recomendo 16GB de RAM e um bom SSD.

Em alguns casos extensões podem estar causando excesso de consumo. O Resharper é ótimo, mas devora recursos se estiver tudo ligado.

Claro que o problema pode ser outro. A pergunta não dá indicações claras que o VS é o problema. Um antivírus pode estar causando impacto em tudo o que o VS faz. É comum isto ocorrer. Pode haver outro problema em outro componente que só aparece quando o VS está ativo. Se eu abrir um monte de coisa mesmo com o VS usando pouca memória poderá começar fazer *swap* como louco.

Comment: Obrigado. Irei providenciar mais um pente de memória.

Comment: 16GB é demasiado para a maior parte dos projectos. A nao ser claro que trabalhe com várias instancias do visual studio abertas (mais de 3). É comum pensar que uma máquina de desenvolvimento consome muitos recursos, mas a verdade é que normalmente nao consome (Consumia muitos recursos sim há 30 anos atrás, mas isso era porque os recursos eram mais escassos). É claro se o projecto for megalomono (google) se calhar os 16GB sao necessários

Comment: Há 30 anos atrás só se rodava um software de cada vez, o sistema operacional ocupava alguns poucos KB e só o compilador era usado e os projetos eram minúsculos em comparação à hoje. O problema não é só o VS, é tudo o que roda junto, se ele rodasse sozinho na máquina e nada mais não precisaria disso tudo, mas ninguém roda só ele, nem é possível.

Answer (score 4):

Apenas para complementar o @Maniero, pode ficar tranquilo, o seu ainda está baixo. Abri um projeto pequeno qualquer aqui e coloquei pra rodar (não estou *debugando*), e já passa dos 300 MB

[image: Consumo das aplicação pelo gerenciado de tarefas]

Answer (score 3):

Milhares (talvez milhões) de desenvolvedores utilizam o Visual Studio todos os dias profissionalmente. Lentidão não é uma reclamação comum.

Se a depuração está lenta para você, as causas mais prováveis são:

- Sua máquina é obsoleta. Infelizmente nem sempre temos os recursos físicos que gostaríamos.
- O código da sua página é lento. 270 Megabytes de consumo de memória, em 2017, é pouco. Até o navegador que você utiliza para acessar o Stack Overflow deve consumir mais do que isso. Lentidão nem sempre é falta de memória - pode ser também um ou mais algoritmos precisando de otimizações. Ou pode ser que o que a página precisa fazer seja algo que realmente demore mesmo.
- Sua página acessa um recurso para o qual a latência é alta. Isso pode acontecer se você acessar uma base de dados em outra máquina e o ping for alto.
- O computador está ocupado com outras coisas. Veja a aba "Performance"/"Desempenho" do gerenciador de tarefas. Se o disco estiver em 100%, essa é a real causa da lentidão. Dica: se na aba detalhes você encontrar um [programa de "telemetria"](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-performance/disabling-windows-compatability-telemetry/f1437548-84ae-4421-9a07-45feb17cab86) da Microsoft, feche. Nos últimos dois anos isso tem sido uma dor de cabeça pra muita gente, pois deixa seu disco no 100% por horas.